# Get value of variable used in Access report

Tags: ms-access, excel, vba

I have a report ("rptEstimate") used as part of a larger program that runs in Access. This report has a text field, with the expression =Nz([txtTaxTotal],0)+Nz([txtSubTotal],0). Where can I find the value for txtTaxTotal and txtSubTotal? Is there some way to see which tables are linked to a specific report?

I'm looking to export those values to a spreadsheet, probably via Excel VBA but I need to isolate them first.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look for the record source of the report. In design view, you will find it on the property sheet on the data tab. In addition, check for a control on the report called `txtSubTotal`, this may be bound to a field from the record source. You can select the name of a control on the property sheet, and the control itself will be highlighted.

Comment: @mwolfe02 Ah ... well, the OP is speedreeder :)

Comment: The RecordSource appears to be qryQuote, which I would assume to be a Query. How can I access that?

Comment: You can click the three little dots to the right of the query name on the record source line of the property sheet. In addition, you will find queries listed in the database window, or in code, you can refer to `currentdb.querydefs("qryQuote").sql`.

Comment: Well I'm learning a ton today, but unfortunately the variable I'm looking for is nowhere to be found in that query. The control source for txtSubTotal is =DSum("DiscountExtPrice","qryEstimateItemTotals","[EstimateID] =" & [EstimateID])

and the control source for txtTaxTotal is =round_tsb(Nz(IIf(Forms!frmEstimates!CustomerID.Column(7)=-1,IIf(IsNull(DSum("[TaxAmtDisc]","qryEstimateItemTotals","[EstimateID]=" & [EstimateID])),0,DSum("[TaxAmtDisc]","qryEstimateItemTotals","[EstimateID]=" & [EstimateID])),0)),2)

I don't know if that helps

Comment: What that says is that you have a domain aggregate function that sums DiscountExtPrice field in the query qryEstimateItemTotals where EstimateID equals EstimateID on the for, that is, it varied from row to row. Similarly for the next reference.

Comment: So what I'm bringing away from this is that it would be a massive headache to try and get this data into an Excel Spreadsheet. Damn.

Comment: Do not despair. You can export a report to Excel from Access. It may or may not be pretty depending on the report, but it will be a step in the right direction. Which version(s) are you on?

Comment: I'm running Access and Excel 2010. Come to think of it, I actually need to import to Excel from Access (.mdb file). Not export from Access to Excel. The difference being that my users would have the spreadsheet open, they would click a CommandButton and the data would get pulled from the Access database and show up in the spreadsheet.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/18934/discussion-between-remou-and-speedreeder)